# How to find the instance by the interface they implements?

Tags: java

I have 2 java classes extends from 2 interface which are inherit relationship like below:

```
interface Base{}
interface Sub extends Base{}

class BaseImpl implements Base{}
class SubImpl implements Sub{}
```

Then I have one Manager class to provide add and findByClass method.

```
class Manager{
    List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public void add(Object o){
        list.add(o);
    }

    public List<Object> findByClass(Class clazz){
        //todo: add find logic
    }
}
```

And I add instances of BaseImpl and SubImpl to Manager and want to query them by interface class as below: return BaseImpl and SubImpl when query by Base interface class and return SubImpl only when query by Sub interface class.

```
    Manager m = new Manager();
    m.add(new BaseImpl());
    m.add(new SubImpl());

    m.findByClass(Base.class); //return BaseImpl and SubImpl
    m.findByClass(Sub.class); //return SubImpl only!
```

My question is how to implement the findByClass method in Manager?

Comment: What exactly do you want to know? What do you mean by "are inherit relationship"? The `BaseImpl` class is implementing the `Base` interface, what else do you want to know from this?

Comment: Does [`Class#getSuperClass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSuperclass--) do what you want to do? i.e. `new SubImpl().getClass().getSuperClass() == new BaseImpl().getClass()`

Answer (score 2):

> `new BaseImpl().getClass();`

This is a silly way to do `BaseImpl.class` - that one does not require a no-args constructor, does not require a non-abstract class, and doesn't create a pointless instance.

> `Class<? extends BaseImpl>`

Similarly, needlessly complicated.

Just write:

```
Class<BaseImpl> base = BaseImpl.class;
```

> How to get the inherit relationship from class instance?

`base.getSuperclass()` and `base.getInterfaces()` are the methods you want. You'd have to recursively call it all, repeatedly, until you have created a complete list of all types for both `base` and `sub` and then you can check if there is overlap.

This is a bizarre thing to want to do, so maybe you want to take a step back and explain *why* you think you need this. Trivially, **all** classes **always** share 'a relationship', as everything extends `java.lang.Object`.

If you merely want to know if e.g. `SubImpl.class` is a subtype of BaseImpl, there is a method for that:

```
System.out.println(BaseImpl.class.isAssignableFrom(SubImpl.class));
> true
```

Comment: +1 for the interpretation and mentioning [`Class#isAssignableFrom(Class)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom-java.lang.Class-). If you are wanting to find out if an _instance_ shares a base class, you could use `instanceof` even: `(new SubImpl() instanceof BaseImpl) == true` (or   `subimpl instanceof BaseImpl` if you already have an instance)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Class#getSuperClass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSuperclass--) to get the superclass of a class:

```
System.out.println(SubImpl.class.getSuperClass() == BaseImpl.class); // true
System.out.println(new SubImpl().getClass().getSuperClass() == new BaseImpl().getClass()); // true
```